# How to mimic Home Key of Centos or windows in terminal of OSx?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

I just miss the ability to go to first position of the shell with just 1 keyboard stroke, which I use it often at my office on CentOS ?

I know I can go by Option + left key or Option + Right key to jump word to word but that doesnt help much .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried fn+left? I'm no CentOS expert, but this works for me exactly as the Home key does when I'm using an external keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-A and Ctrl-E go to the beginning and end of the command line; this is a Bash thing, not tied to any OS or terminal.